# Refresh WPF-Control by code

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, refresh

I am trying to disable a button for denying a spam click on this button.

I used a Refresh delegate to Render invoke the control but it appears as enabled.
The connect()-Methode is taking about 4 seconds in witch the button is shown as enabled.

Where is the problem ?

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{

   private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };


   public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
   {
      uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
   }
}


private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
    buttonConnect.IsEnabled = false;
    buttonConnect.Refresh();

    if (buttonConnect.Content.Equals("Connect"))
    {
        connect();
    }
    else
    {
        disconnect();
    }
    buttonConnect.IsEnabled = true;
    buttonConnect.Refresh();
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since all that appears to happen on the UI-Thread the UI has no time to update in-between, you need to run your task on a background thread and change the UI again on completion (e.g. use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) which already has a `RunWorkerCompleted` event).

e.g.

```
button.IsEnabled = false;
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (s, _) =>
{
    //Long-running things.
};
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,_) => button.IsEnabled = true;
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: +1 I've seen lots of answers to this question on SO. This is the most flexible and reliable I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

even better, instead of messing around with events, why not use ICommand binding and there you can implement CanExecute which you can return true/false depending on whether you want to enable/disable the button

[Great example here on ICommand](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/03/20/icommand-is-like-a-chocolate-cake.aspx)

Comment: My vote here. Never manage the WPF UI in a old-fashion style.

Comment: exactly. more code to manage UI state, where as WPF already has nice ICommand binding!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the priority of a method to Render, which does not actually do any rendering.

I would say using an asynchronous call would be the best action to take here, giving the layout engine time to render:

```
private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait; 
    buttonConnect.IsEnabled = false; 

    Action action = buttonConnect.Content.Equals("Connect") ? connect : disconnect;

    new Action(() => {
        action();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                buttonConnect.IsEnabled = true;
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
            });
    }).BeginInvoke(null, null);
}
```